# ObjectMapping + Alamofire 通信を行うメソッドをどこからでも使えるように共通化したい

Tags: swift, alamofire

API通信を行う際の処理を共通化しようとしています。
Mappperの箇所でコンパイルエラーが出てしまい、これを修正する方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
func call(method: Alamofire.Method, url: String, params: [String: AnyObject], res: Mappable) -> Observable<[Any]> {
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
        Alamofire.request(method, url, parameters: params)
            .responseJSON { response in
                log?.debug(response.description)
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    guard let result = Mapper<res>().mapArray(value) else {
                        return
                    }
                    observer.on(.Next(result))
                    observer.on(.Completed)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    observer.on(.Error(error))
                }
        }
        return AnonymousDisposable { }
    }
}
```

[image: 現在のエラー]

↑を↓のように記述したいです。

[image: こういう風に記述したいです。]

Comment: どんなエラーが出ていますか？コンパイルエラーのメッセージは何ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ジェネリクスで記述しようと試行錯誤していますが、コンパイルエラーを消すことができません。現在はメソッドを使用する箇所でMapping処理を行うようにしています。